# How do I crop multiple images using PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, crop, removing-whitespace

I've just started using PIL with python and I need help with detecting the photos and cropping out multiple images on a single white background with different sizes.
I've used `Image.crop` and `ImageChop.difference`, but that only crops out one image.

```
def trim(im):
bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, im.getpixel((0,0)))
diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
bbox = diff.getbbox()
if bbox:
    return im.crop(bbox)
else:
    print("No image detected")


image1 = Image.open('multiple.jpg')
image2 = trim(image1)
image2.show()
```

Comment: May be loop around what you are doing and pass different images?

Comment: its better to share your code, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are the images you want to crop from the white background all the same size? If so, you can divide the image into equal sizes and then loop over the image and crop it. Otherwise you could add the pixel offsets to crop in a list. For example, if your image is 900px and you want the image cropped at every 300px, you can crop the image at pixels 0-299, then pixels 300-599 and then pixels 600-899

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "cropping out multiple images on a white background". Also, how does that relate to opening them as different files?

Comment: Do you mean you have just one file which is like a scan of say 6 images arranged on the platten of your scanner? How about showing us the input and expected output?

Answer (score 3):

I think something like the following is what you are looking for:

```
import os

from PIL import Image

# Crops the image and saves it as "new_filename"
def crop_image(img, crop_area, new_filename):
    cropped_image = img.crop(crop_area)
    cropped_image.save(new_filename)

# The x, y coordinates of the areas to be cropped. (x1, y1, x2, y2)
crop_areas = [(180, 242, 330, 566), (340, 150, 900, 570)]

image_name = 'download.jpg'
img = Image.open(image_name)

# Loops through the "crop_areas" list and crops the image based on the coordinates in the list
for i, crop_area in enumerate(crop_areas):
    filename = os.path.splitext(image_name)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(image_name)[1]
    new_filename = filename + '_cropped' + str(i) + ext

    crop_image(img, crop_area, new_filename)
```

The program works by taking an input image (`download.jpg` in this case), looping through a list of `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` coordinates which represent areas of the images to be cropped, and then passes each image to the `crop_image()` function which takes in the image to be cropped, the coordinates and the new filename for the image to be saved as.

The resulting files are saved as `download_cropped0.jpg` and `download_cropped1.jpg` (in this example). If you want to crop more areas in the image, you'll need to add more tuples in the form of `(x1, y1, x2, y2)` to the `crop_areas` list. You can use a program like paint or photshop to get the coordinates of the image you want to crop from and to.